# Cannot get WholeStory to select & format all text in a Word Doc using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, format

I need to be able to generate a report (in Word) that utilizes a bunch of data that is stored in Excel. I am having issues when I try to format the entire Word Document (the report title AND everything that I have copied over from Excel) so that everything is single spaced and has no paragraph spacing before or after. The "WholeStory" command/selection does not work. Thanks in advance for your help!!!

```
Sub Generate_Report()
    Dim appWD As Word.Application 
    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWD.Visible = True
    appWD.Documents.Add

  <<Sub where I move/arrange data from a bunch of sheets to Sheets("Template")>>

    Sheets("Template").UsedRange.Copy
    With appWD.Selection
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Name = "Calibri Light (Headings)"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .TypeText ("NAME OF REPORT TITLE") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Paste
    End With
    With appWD.WholeStory.ParagraphFormat
        .SpaceBefore = 0
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
    End With
    Sheets("Template").Cells.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it just the "With appWD.WholeStory.ParagraphFormat" part that doesn't work?

Comment: Yep. That's the only part that I cannot figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try after 1st End with

```
appWD.Selection.WholeStory
With appWD.Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceDouble
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. With both scenarios I get the compile error "Expected function or variable" when it gets to the .WholeStory command. I believe I have set the object library reference correctly (but could certainly have made a mistake) as word opens and everything else works when I remove the lines of code pertaining to paragraph spacing requirements ... which is why I am so confused

Answer (score 0):

All you need between 'Sheets("Template").UsedRange.Copy' and 'Sheets("Template").Cells.ClearContents' is:

```
With appWD.ActiveDocument.Range
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light (Headings)"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    .TypeText ("NAME OF REPORT TITLE") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    .Characters.Last.Paste
    With .ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .SpaceBefore = 0
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using Range, but keep getting a compile error "Method or data member not found."

Comment: Without knowing what appWd is defined as, one has to guess. Try With appWD.ActiveDocument.Range. Code in answer updated

Comment: Thanks for the response. Guess I just needed to change my selection --- adding "appWD.Selection.WholeStory" outside of the original with statement did the trick :)

Comment: Working with Selections is really inefficient. Did you at least try the code change I both suggested and made?